# How to stop Stemming from removing the letters that change the meaning of the word?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to select stemming or lemmatizing or both for NLP processing. When I do stemming, it takes away important suffixes. When I do lemmatizing, it does not reduce some words.

For example,

```
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer

tokens = ['carry', 'xy', 'known', 'size', 'may', 'use', 'column', 'value', 'contracting']

stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
stems = []

for wrd in tokens:
   stems.append(stemmer.stem(wrd))
print(stems)
```

This is producing the following stemming output:

```
['carry', 'xy', 'known', 'siz', 'may', 'us', 'column', 'valu', 'contract']
```

where it rightly reduces `contracting` to `contract` but does not do the same for `use` or `size` or `value`.

```
lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
lems []
for wrd in tokens:
   lems.append(lem.lemmatize(wrd))
print(lems)
```

This is producing the following lemmatizing output:

```
['carry', 'xy', 'known', 'size', 'may', 'use', 'column', 'value', 'contracting']
```

where `contracting` is not reduced to `contract` but others are rightly captured.

Which would be the best option to go with if the data is either large or small?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`spacy` lemmatizer](https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer):

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

tokens = ['carry', 'xy', 'known', 'size', 'may', 'use', 'column', 'value', 'contracting']
result = [nlp(t)[0].lemma_ for t in tokens]
print(result)
# => ['carry', 'xy', 'know', 'size', 'may', 'use', 'column', 'value', 'contract']
```

Comment: When I run it, it does not do `contracting` to `contract`

Comment: @VancePyton Just re-ran the same code as above and it works on my side.